# Extract 7.100.023c, 13,134.057d@015_4019 cases

Tags: regex, text-extraction

I need to weed out numeration of Mahabharat Shlokas.
Simple Case:

```
7.100.023c devānāṃ yasya yā yonir vānarā ṛṣka rākṣasāḥ
7.100.024a tām eva viviśuḥ sarve devān nikṣipya cāmbhasi
7.100.024c tathā svargagataṃ sarvaṃ kṛtvā lokagurur divam
7.100.025a jagāma tridaśaiḥ sārdhaṃ hṛṣṭair hṛṣṭo mahāmatiḥ
```

Harder Case:

```
13,120.009  vyāsa uvāca
13,120.009a bho bho viprarṣabha śrīman mā vyathiṣṭhāḥ kathaṃ cana
13,119.008b*0599_01 śakaṭavrajaś ca sumahān āgataś ca yadṛcchayā
13,119.008b*0599_02 cakrākrameṇa bhinnaś ca kīṭaḥ prāṇān mumoca ha
13,119.008b*0599_03 saṃbhūtaḥ kṣatriyakule prasādād amitaujasaḥ
13,134.057d@015_4018    hṛdi kāmamayaś citro mohasaṃcayasaṃbhavaḥ
13,134.057d@015_4019    ajñānarūḍhamūlas tu vidhitsāpariṣecanaḥ
```

`18,005.053x@003_0054   dharmamaṅgalalābhaṃ ca śrutvaitat prāpnuyān naraḥ
18,005.053x@003_0055    bhāti sarveṣu vedeṣu ratiḥ sarvatra jantuṣu`

To make `7.100.023c` gone is not hard. But sometimes there are only numbers `13,120.009`, stars `13,119.008b*0599_01` and even @ `13,134.057d@015_4018`, so I failed at http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/1 Not sure how to combine all of them, thanks.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `/^\d[\d.a-z_*@,]+/gm` did the magic - I need only words, no numbers, to count CVC patterns. Everything works as expected!

Comment: How about `(AVŚ_20,143.7a) iheha yad vāṃ samanā papṛkṣe seyam asme sumatir vājaratnā |
(AVŚ_20,143.7c) uruṣyataṃ jaritāraṃ yuvaṃ ha śritaḥ kāmo nāsatyā yuvadrik ||7||` I tried to add \(, but did not worked out with `^\d[\d.a-z_*@,]+\s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d+[.,]\d{3}\.\d{3}[a-z]?[*@]?\d*_?\d*|\(\S+\)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/9

Comment: Thanks, works with all except `18,005.053x@003_0054` So I'll go `/^\d[\d.a-z_*@,]+/gm` way - it's so compact. My brain gets hot.

Comment: @gasyoun try now.works for `18,005.053x@003_0054` too

Comment: great, how about `(AVŚ_20,143.7c)` - have missed this case.